# ClassNotFound error during class verification with ASM's Class Verifier (org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckClassAdapter)

Tags: bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

So here is a snippet of bytecode which i am trying to verify using ASM's class Verifier:

```
public <init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 1
    SIPUSH 2048
    NEW org/apache/xerces/impl/msg/XMLMessageFormatter
    DUP
    INVOKESPECIAL org/apache/xerces/impl/msg/XMLMessageFormatter.<init> ()V
    INVOKESTATIC java/util/Locale.getDefault ()Ljava/util/Locale;
    INVOKESPECIAL org/apache/xerces/impl/io/UTF8Reader.<init> (Ljava/io/InputStream;ILorg/apache/xerces/util/MessageFormatter;Ljava/util/Locale;)V
    RETURN
    MAXSTACK = 5
    MAXLOCALS = 2
```

this is part of a larger class org/apache/xerces/impl/io/UTF8Reader. Now, when i run the the bytecode of this class through the Class verifier provided by ASM, I get the following results:

```
org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException: **Error at instruction 7: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.util.MessageFormatter**
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Analyzer.analyze(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckClassAdapter.verify(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckClassAdapter.verify(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckClassAdapter.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.util.MessageFormatter
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.SimpleVerifier.getClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.SimpleVerifier.isAssignableFrom(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.SimpleVerifier.isSubTypeOf(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.BasicVerifier.naryOperation(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.BasicVerifier.naryOperation(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Frame.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V
00000 UTF8Reader InputStream  :  :     ALOAD 0
00001 UTF8Reader InputStream  : UTF8Reader  :     ALOAD 1
00002 UTF8Reader InputStream  : UTF8Reader InputStream  :     SIPUSH 2048
00003 UTF8Reader InputStream  : UTF8Reader InputStream I  :     NEW org/apache/xerces/impl/msg/XMLMessageFormatter
00004 UTF8Reader InputStream  : UTF8Reader InputStream I XMLMessageFormatter  :     DUP
00005 UTF8Reader InputStream  : UTF8Reader InputStream I XMLMessageFormatter XMLMessageFormatter  :     INVOKESPECIAL org/apache/xerces/impl/msg/XMLMessageFormatter.<init> ()V
00006 UTF8Reader InputStream  : UTF8Reader InputStream I XMLMessageFormatter  :     INVOKESTATIC java/util/Locale.getDefault ()Ljava/util/Locale;
00007 UTF8Reader InputStream  : UTF8Reader InputStream I XMLMessageFormatter Locale  :     INVOKESPECIAL org/apache/xerces/impl/io/UTF8Reader.<init> (Ljava/io/InputStream;ILorg/apache/xerces/util/MessageFormatter;Ljava/util/Locale;)V
00008 ?        :     RETURN
```

I am highly confused by this last bit... why is it giving out a ClassNotFound exception for the org/apache/xerces/util/MessageFormatter object at line 7?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm familiar with Java not ASM.  Some ideas (apologies if these are too obvious):  So you are loading UTF8Reader as bytecode via ASM?  Is the entire xerces jar getting loaded that way?  Or just some class(es)?  How about MessageFormatter?  If not, where do you expect it to enter the classpath and get loaded?  (May help to know how you're invoking ASM.)

Comment: So i am loading the UTF8Reader and MessageFormatter via java.lang.instrument. I am basically writing a java agent that does load time instrumentation of the classes. Now, while loading the bytecode of the classes i store them separately in their own files, which i use to verify later in an offline process, i.e. after the program has executed successfully. Mind you the program is executing successfully. thanks.

Comment: also, this might help as well, http://mail-archive.ow2.org/asm/2011-08/msg00051.html does this make any sense? thanks again.

Comment: If you're seeing the same issue as in that link, sounds like you need to change the order in which the classes are loaded. Can you load MessageFormatter first? This may be a tricky process if you want to instrument many dependencies. I'm sure there's an automatic way of obtaining a good loading order (read up on classloaders), but worst case you could output and use the order from another tool (such as verbose logging of normal classloader operation). You may wish to revisit your requirements before taking such a leap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASM's verifier tool does check validity of each stack and variable slot as per JVM specification. One of the checks is that values in all variable and stack slots have the same types at merge points. So, this implementation loads classes to find common super types.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. The checker was not able to find the class file for org/apache/xerces/util/MessageFormatter when it wanted to load it, so it was unable to verify it correctly. Once i included it in the classpath, it all worked out.